# Using AJAX to retrieve values from <select> dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to retrieve the value of my dropdown on change, and post it to my PHP (at the moment, the PHP is just `var_dump`, for debugging purposes)

I'm stuck at posting the selected value to my AJAX, seemingly there no change.

I Using WP framework to load scripts and run them through `admin-ajax.php` -- I've been 
using this approach for others AJAX functions, and it is working.

I have a dropdown list, like this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">                        
 <select name="count" class="count">
  <option value='1'>1</option>  
  <option value='2'>2</option>  
  <option value='3'>3</option>  
  <option value='4'>4</option>  
  <option value='5'>5</option>  
 </select>
<input class="koordinator_id" type="hidden" name="koordinator_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['coordinator_id'] ?>">     
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.count').change(function () {

        alert("Whyunoalert?");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: (my_ajax_script.ajaxurl),
            data: ({
                action: 'generate',
                koordinator_id: $('input[name=$"koordinator_id"]').val(),
                id: $('select.count').val()
            }),
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Data changed:" + msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
function generate() {     
    $count = $_POST['id'];
    var_dump($count);
    $koordinator_id = $_POST['koordinator_id'];
    var_dump($koordinator_id);
}
```

**EDIT**

I've changed the code accordingly to the first three comments. Now my code executes the AJAX but still no var_dump are made in the php file. Thanks for the help so far, hope you can do a bit more. Also i've added the functions.php code , where the php function is bound and the redirect to ajax-admin.php is setup.

**functions.php**

```
function load_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script('local_jquery', '/wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme/scripts/scripts.js');
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_func', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/ajax_implementation.js');

}
if (!is_admin())
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
add_action('template_redirect', 'load_scripts');

$dirName = dirname(__FILE__);
$baseName = basename(realpath($dirName));
require_once ("$dirName/ajax_functions.php");

add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_approve", "generate");
add_action("wp_ajax_approve", "generate");
```

**2nd EDIT**

removed this from the ajax: (was from old copy-paste)

```
     dataType: 'html',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are firing ajax `onchange` event why did you wrap them in the form tag? remove it if no use other than `onchange` event.

Second is you're using `action: 'generate'` in your `ajax function` but you're not hooking the right action in your functions file of php

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_YOUR_ACTION", "METHOD");
add_action("wp_ajax_YOUR_ACTION", "METHOD");
```

So it would be

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_generate", "generate");
add_action("wp_ajax_generate", "generate");
```

Last but not least always exit your ajax method call, so make sure it won't fall below.

```
function generate() {     
    $count = $_POST['id'];
    var_dump($count);
    $koordinator_id = $_POST['koordinator_id'];
    var_dump($koordinator_id);
    exit;
}
```

Also as @Krishna answer remove the `$` sign `unexpected expression`

```
koordinator_id: jQuery('input[name=$"koordinator_id"]').val(),
```

Need to be:

```
koordinator_id: jQuery('input[name="koordinator_id"]').val(),
```

Comment: Thansk for taking your time and writing a good explanation. very helpfull and solved everything. Thx alot! <3

Answer (score 2):

The selector `$('input[name=$"koordinator_id"]')` is wrong in your data line. The syntax for input name ending with some string is `$('input[name$=somestring]']`.

Use this instead:

```
$('input[name$="koordinator_id"]') // '$' needs to be before '='
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `{` after the `.ready(function()`. Fix it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.count').change(function () {
        alert("Whyunoalert?");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'my_ajax_script.ajaxurl',
            data: ({
                action: 'generate',
                koordinator_id: $('input[name=$"koordinator_id"]').val(),
                id: $('select.count').val()
            }),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Data changed:" + msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Pjust Did you change the `url`? If yes, edit your post to the current code, please.

Comment: Yes i did, that had no effect, and i have a function, with brackets()  around the url, and that works. so i dont think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
$('.count').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'my_ajax_script.ajaxurl',
        data: {'action': 'generate', 'koordinator_id': $('input[name=koordinator_id]').val(), 'id': $('.count').val()}),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data changed:" + msg);
        }
    });       
});
});
```

Also avoid using of php short tags.Sometimes it cause problems if your php version doesnt support short  tags.So change this

```
<input class="koordinator_id" type="hidden" name="koordinator_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['coordinator_id'] ?>">
```